# App not installed after disconnecting via USB on Android Studio

Tags: android

I connected my phone via usb to run my app on Android Studio. It's working fine when connected but when I disconnect my phone from my PC, the app is no longer installed. Does anybody know how to autoinstall apps on Android studio on my phone when I'm running it?

Comment: `to run my app on Android Studio`. Apps cannot run on Android studio. Only on Android devices or emulators. Where are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

check you manifests file and make sure that your activity contains

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

and also check your application is there in setting>all applications